# CURL - HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request- SharePoint API error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to download some data in the form of `json` from a `SharePoint` API. I was able to do it using `WGET`:

`wget --user user --password password --header='Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' "URL"`

and I am trying to do the same thing with CURL.

I tried using different headers and authentication mechanisms, but it always gives me the bad request error. Below are the commands I tried:

`curl -v --user user:password "URL"
 curl -v --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' "URL"
 curl -v --ntlm --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/xml' "URL"
 curl -v --anyauth --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/xml' "URL"`

Below is the output I get:

```
* About to connect() to sharepoint2.domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx... connected
* Connected to sharepoint2.domain.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET <path> HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: sharepoint2.domain.com
> Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 21:45:06 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 311
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
* Closing connection #0
```

I am not sure what's going wrong. How do I solve the issue and pull the data with CURL ?

**UPDATE:**

I tried putting the `-L` in the command in case there is an issue with redirect as pointed out by @Nicholas in his answer, but it's still the same error :( . I don't think it is really a redirect issue because I am getting the `400 bad request` response from the API right?.

My URL is like this: `.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('new list')/items`. I guessed the error has something to do with GetByTitle('new list')..so I tried giving it a different URL: `.../_api/web/lists` and it didn't give me the 400 bad request Error! but instead I got `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`. SO my intial error had something to do with encoding the `URL` ?

I wanted to see why Wget is working and used the `--debug` option to print out the whole log and I found something interesting:

```
[~ /data/home/user/pir]$wget --user user --debug --password password --header='Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' "URL"
Setting --password (password) to password
Setting --header (header) to Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

--2018-02-13 07:13:08--  URL
Host “sharepoint2.domain.com” has not issued a general basic challenge.
Resolving sharepoint2.domain.com... xx.xx.xx.xx
Caching sharepoint2.domain.com => xx.xx.xx.xx
Connecting to sharepoint2.domain.com|xx.xx.xx.xx|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000002229e70 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET path HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Host: sharepoint2.domain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
SPRequestGuid: 90174a9e-d921-1018-c709-d64cd2403a12
request-id: 90174a9e-d921-1018-c709-d64cd2403a12
SPRequestDuration: 29
SPIisLatency: 1
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4859
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:13:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16

---response end---
401 Unauthorized
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Skipping 16 bytes of body: [401 UNAUTHORIZED] done.
Empty NTLM message, starting transaction.
Creating a type-1 NTLM message.
Reusing existing connection to sharepoint2.domain.com:80.
Reusing fd 3.

---request begin---
GET <path> HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Host: sharepoint2.domain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAAgIAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAA=

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAABAAEADgAAAAGAoEC33/kD9suGK8AAAAAAAAAAOAA4AA8AAAABgOAJQAAAA9DT1JQAgAIAEMATwBSAFAAAQAUAFcAUABOAE8AQQBTAFAAQwAwADYABAAsAGMAbwByAHAALgBiAGEAbgBrAG8AZgBhAG0AZQByAGkAYwBhAC4AYwBvAG0AAwBSAHcAcABuAG8AYQBzAHAAYwAwADYALgB1AHMAcABuAG8AYwB0AC4AYQBtAHIAcwAuAGIAYQBuAGsAbwBmAGEAbQBlAHIAaQBjAGEALgBjAG8AbQAFACIAYgBhAG4AawBvAGYAYQBtAGUAcgBpAGMAYQAuAGMAbwBtAAcACADOsXRkzKTTAQAAAAA=
SPRequestGuid: 90174a9e-8925-1018-c709-d7cd9dd3150d
request-id: 90174a9e-8925-1018-c709-d7cd9dd3150d
SPRequestDuration: 1
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4859
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:13:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

---response end---
401 Unauthorized
Skipping 0 bytes of body: [] done.
Received a type-2 NTLM message.
Creating a type-3 NTLM message.
Reusing existing connection to sharepoint2.domain.com:80.
Reusing fd 3.

---request begin---
GET <path> HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Host: sharepoint2.domain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAEcAAAAYABgAXwAAAAAAAABAAAAABwAHAEAAAAAAAAAARwAAAAAAAAB3AAAAAYIAAHpraDl4Y2w02/8GDGRzkuXXcgWtte6c6h6ggw8yerZmu6ewFZpvd9hNAYfP/XDSQWvE5Eukuy0=

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 13:13:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:13:08 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 4936
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: 90174a9e-c925-1018-c709-d9b4ad681772
request-id: 90174a9e-c925-1018-c709-d9b4ad681772
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4859
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 13:13:13 GMT
Connection: close

---response end---
200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: “items.5”
```

The `Wget` request fails with `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` but it sill tries executing the request a total of 3 times and it gets connected 3rd time. and it does this all the time.

Could it be that I have to pass some argument to `CURL` to keep trying even after it failed with  `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue has to do with the difference between wget and curl with respect to 302 responses.

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/938391/url-works-in-wget-but-not-in-curl-related-to-apt

> Note the HTTP 302 status code. This is a redirect, meaning that the
>   URL provided maps to another URL. Wget by default follows redirects,
>   curl does not. Browsers also usually follow redirects by default. In
>   order to make curl follow redirects, use the option -L or --location.
>
> Quoting from the man page,
>
> -L, --location (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header
>   and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request
>   on the new place.

So use the `-L` command line argument to curl and you will be right as rain.

UPDATE:

After you sent the wget debug output, we found wget is cycling between the attempts to authenticate and landing on ntlm. so by removing `--negotiate` from the curl while keeping `-L` helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it hoping it would work, but it still gives me the same error! :(

Comment: hmm.... can you try just getting to the Home.aspx page without using the header to see if that works? let's try just downloading some aspx page and get that working, then go from there. what web service are you trying to call?

Comment: Here's the command I used: `curl -v --ntlm --negotiate --user user:password -H 'Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' "URL"`

Comment: ok try: `curl -v --ntlm --negotiate --user 'user:password'  http://yoursharepoint.domain/SitePages/Home.aspx` and see if that works

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work. What baffles me is that `wget` gives me no trouble where as `CURL` doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986395/why-does-curl-not-work-but-wget-works and https://askubuntu.com/questions/938391/url-works-in-wget-but-not-in-curl-related-to-apt
it's 302 redirect issue and i updated my answer for you

Comment: I tried putting the `-L` in the command, but it's still the same error :( . Could it really be a redirect issue? because I am getting the `400 bad request` response from the API right? . My URL is like this:  `.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('new list')/items`. I guessed the error has something to do with `GetByTitle('new list')`..so I tried giving it a different URL: `.../_api/web/lists` and it didn't give me the `400 bad request` Error! but instead I got `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: and on the console, this was also printed: `* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : Server not found in Kerberos databaseWWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` . could this error indicate an issue with kerberos? Then I tried removing the `--ntlm` and `--negotiate` arguments. But it still the same `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`. So to solve my `400 bad request` error, I think I should encode the URL or something? and after that is done, How do I solve this `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` error?

Comment: Updated the question with some interesting findings.

Comment: it's beause it's cycling between the attempts to authenticate and landing on ntlm. try removing `--negotiate` while keeping `-L`

Comment: Wow that worked!! :D I am getting the `json` response!! Thanks a lot! 
Any ideas on how to encode my URL to access the items from a list without getting the `400 bad request` ?

Comment: see https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
and use single quotes to surround your urls

Comment: Thanks for everything. I am able to get it working. Please edit your answer to include the points from our discussion and I'll approve it. :)

Comment: ok i updated it.